# How to get id when I click Object Card?

Tags: ajax

how to get id when I click the card, I get id in concole.log .
but I don't know get id when card was clicked.
here is the code :

```
    $.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_leagues.php?',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : {
        's' : 'Soccer'
    },

    success: function(result){
        let league = result.countrys;

        $.each(league, function(i, data){
            $('#club-list').append(`
                <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
                    <div class="card shadow" onCLick="console.log(`+data.idLeague+`)">
                      <img src="`+ data.strBadge +`" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">`+ data.strLeague +`</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`);
        });

        $('.card').on('click', function(){

            $.ajax({

                url : 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookup_all_teams.php?',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    // 'id' : '4328'
                    'id' : /* HOW TO GET ID FROM CARD WHEN USER CLICK CARD ? */
                },

                success: function(result){
                    let team = result.teams;


                    $.each(team, function(i, data){
                        $('#club-detail').append(`
                            <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
                                <div class="card shadow">
                                  <img src="`+ data.strTeamBadge +`" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="...">
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text">`+ data.strTeam +`</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`);
                    });
                    // window.location.href = "league.php";
                    console.log(team);
                }

            });



        });
    } 
});
```

https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookup_all_teams.php?id=4328 /* HOW TO GET ID WHEN USER CLICK CARD ? */

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzuko.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_leagues.php?',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : {
        's' : 'Soccer'
    },

    success: function(result){
        let league = result.countrys;

        $.each(league, function(i, data){
            $('#club-list').append(`
                <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
                    <div class="card shadow" data-id="${data.idLeague}">
                      <img src="`+ data.strBadge +`" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">`+ data.strLeague +`</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`);
        });

        $(document).on('click','.card', function(e){

  console.log(this.dataset.id);



        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: console.log is undefined bro !

Comment: console.log(e.target.dataset.id)

Comment: yes bro i know you typo, i have been changed to target, but still undefined

Comment: sorry for the trouble this works (tested):- console.log(this.dataset.id)

Comment: thank you so much bro , now my object can send id to url .

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of id. because multiple id with same key won't work

Comment: I have been changed id to class bro .